# Vuex: Data sometimes gets 'undefined' during hard refresh

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vuex for the first time and I have this occasional problem in console:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Info: render
```

***Any idea on how I can fix this problem?***

Here is my setup:

> **In Vuex (store.js) I have a getter like so:**

```
state: {
    statuses: []
  },
actions: {
    async fetchStatuses({ commit }) {
      try {
        const response = await ApiService.getStatusFlags()
        commit('SET_STATUSES', response.data)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
},
  getters: {
    getStatusById: state => id => {
      return state.statuses.find(status => status.id === id)
    },
    ...snip...
```

And on the page where I am calling this getter is like so:

> **IssueDetail.vue template:**

```
   <span class="badge badge-success">{{ getStatusById(issue.status).name }}</span>
```

> **IssueDetail.vue script section:**

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'IssueDetail',
  data() {
    return {
      isBusy: true,
      issue_id: this.$route.params.id,
      issue: ''
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getIssue()
    this.isBusy = false
  },
methods: {
    async getIssue() {
      try {
        this.issue = (await ApiService.getIssue(this.$route.params.id)).data[0]
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    }
},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getStatusById'])
  }
```

Comment: OK, so as I was typing the above question, it made me go line by line and I realized that I probably needed to dispatch a call to 'fetchStatuses'. So, by adding the following line to the created hook:

await this.$store.dispatch('fetchStatuses') seemed to have fixed the problem. However, is this the best way to do it? It seems like it's overkill and at the end of the day I still have verbose language in my template which I was hoping to avoid by using Vuex as well as having to make another API call.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I am facing a similar one

Answer (score 0):

this

```
getStatusById(issue.status).name
```

cannot work with your default value of the **issue** prop. Either change your default value or change getStatusById so it can accept null or undefined as an input param OR change your expression in a template to something like:

```
issue.status? getStatusById(issue.status).name : ''
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that `issue.status? getStatusById(issue.status).name : ''` earlier before posting my question and I still got the `undefined` error. The only way I was able to it to work was by doing a dispatch/fetch of the status state data during the created lifecyle hook. Thanks!